# Drawing a point on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, jpanel

Is there any way to draw a Point on a `JPanel` using the `java.awt.Graphics` class? I couldn't find any such method. Well, there are many methods for drawing lines and other shapes, (e.g `.drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)`, but does `Graphics` lack the implementation to draw the most basic geometrical object?

Comment: You can always draw an oval with a width and height of 1 or 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
g2d.drawOval(5, 5, 100, 100);
```

Or you can check [this](http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/16524-drawing-points-mouse.html) article

Answer (score 18):

Yes It does lack it, you're gonna have to use:

```
.drawLine(x1, y1, x1, y1)
```

(the same location for both source and destination points)